# Make submenu display on min width

Tags: html, css, menu, media-queries

i have a menu with submenu that displays on hover, but when it shows for mobile phones or tablets shows a collapse menu, i want to make the submenu `display` automatic (not on hover) when i rezise the windows for mobile phones or tablets with media queries, how can i do?

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/AD8vB/3/

Thanks.